# Cubes with common faces

Tags: real-analysis

i≤n, then the number of times it appears is 1+2+...+i=i(i+1)2.

If 2n−1≤i≤3n−2, then (symmetry) it appears the same number of times as the number 3n−1−i.

Comment: Number is easy - you mean digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An n × n × n cube**

Consider the day number $i$.

If $i\le n$, then the number of times it appears is $1+2+...+i=\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$.

If $2n-1\le i\le 3n-2$, then (symmetry) it appears the same number of times as the number $3n-1-i$.

If $n< i<2n-1$, then the number of times it appears is $$(i+1-n)+(i-n)+...(n-1)+n+(n-1)+...+(2n-i).$$

Note that it is the third of these formulae which will give the largest number of appearances and this will be when $n$ is as close as possible to being in the middle of the summation.Then $n-(i+1-n)\approx n-(2n-i)$ i.e. $2i+1\approx 3n$.

**Answer (b)**

$7$ appears $\frac{7\times8}{2}=28$ times.

For $13$, we need $4+...+9+10+9+...+7=73$.

**Answer (a)**

$2i+1\approx 3\times 2018$ when $i=3026$ and $3027$.